# T-SQL row count for each table with a WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and have the below query to retrieve the RowCount of all tables that begin with 'IN%'. This works fine.

However, within each 'IN...' table there is a column called 'ErrorFlg' - this can be 0 or 1.

How do I modify the below to also include a new column called 'NoOfErrors' that will count where the 'ErrorFlg = 1' in each table?

```
SELECT        
    ta.name AS TableName, 
    SUM(pa.rows) AS RowCnt
FROM
    sys.tables AS ta 
INNER JOIN
    sys.partitions AS pa ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id 
INNER JOIN
    sys.schemas AS sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE
    (ta.is_ms_shipped = 0) AND (pa.index_id IN (1, 0)) 
    AND (ta.name LIKE 'IN_%')
GROUP BY 
    sc.name, ta.name
ORDER BY 
    TableName, RowCnt DESC
```

Ideal output:

```
TableName    RowCnt   NoOfErrors
--------------------------------
IN_123        100       50
IN_4566       500        2
IN_ABC        250      125
```

Comment: The only way you could do that would be with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Cant you just add a new column  SUM(pa.ErrorFlg) AS NoOfErrors ? Or am i misunderstanding your question
Yep, sorry - misunderstood question, just ignore this comment

Comment: @MikNiller Column name != value in this column. OP is reading from metadata not actual tables. Michael Very easy to achieve in Oracle/PostgreSQL with single query. For SQL Server - cursor/dynamic SQL/ms_foreach table with condition

Comment: The nicest solution is using `EVAL` function equivalent **[demo PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8579914b667f15c1504fdb518796439f)**

Answer (score 0):

As per @Lamu's suggestion, The will create a table variable with your results and then create and execute dynamic statements...

```
Declare @Tbl Table 
(
TableName VarChar(50),
RowCnt Int
)

Insert Into @Tbl
   SELECT    
     ta.name AS TableName, 
     SUM(pa.rows) AS RowCnt 
   FROM
     sys.tables AS ta 
   INNER JOIN 
     sys.partitions AS pa ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id 
   INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas AS sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
   WHERE
     (ta.is_ms_shipped = 0) AND (pa.index_id IN (1, 0)) 
     AND (ta.name LIKE 'IN_%')
   GROUP BY 
     sc.name, ta.name
   ORDER BY 
     TableName, RowCnt DESC


Declare @tblname VarChar(50)
Declare @rowcnt VarChar(10)
Declare @vsql VarChar(Max) = NULL

Declare c Cursor For Select TableName,RowCnt From @Tbl
Open c
Fetch Next From c Into @tblname, @rowcnt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       Set @vsql = 'Select ''' + @tblname +''' As Tbl,''' + @rowcnt + ''' As RowCnt, Count(*) As NoOfErrors From ' + @tblname + ' Where ErrorFlg = 1'
       Exec(@vsql)
       Set @vsql = NULL
       Fetch Next From c Into @tblname, @rowcnt
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I execute I receive loads of errors e.g. Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Import_ABC'.

Comment: The code sample in this answer only knows about two objects as far as I can tell: Tables that begin with the letters 'IN_%' and the column 'ErrorFlg'. I'm not seeing how any objects called 'Import_ABC' come in to play. Is your code looking different than the answer code? The above will either produce records or no records. I don't see how it will throw an error.